# Rotate unity gameobject smoth in the other direction

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation, game-development

i want to rotate (actually just to the left and right side) an object by swiping over the screen. I have working code already but when i swipe from the left to the right of my screen, the whole movement is kind of lagging.
The object has the following script. 
Any help is appreciated... this is driving me crazy. 
Thank you for your time!

```
[ICODE]void Update()
    {
        if (Input.touchCount == 0)
        {
            oldTouchPositions[0] = null;
            oldTouchPositions[1] = null;
        }
        else if (Input.touchCount == 1)
        {
            if (oldTouchPositions[0] == null || oldTouchPositions[1] != null)
            {
                oldTouchPositions[0] = Input.GetTouch(0).position;
                oldTouchPositions[1] = null;
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("Dragging Detected");
                Vector2 newTouchPosition = Input.GetTouch(0).position;

                float dis = (Vector2.Distance((Vector2)oldTouchPositions[0], newTouchPosition)) / 4;


                if (((Vector2)oldTouchPositions[0])[0] < newTouchPosition[0])
                {
                    //Debug.Log("Left"); dunno if correct
                    vertical = (vertical - velcoidadeDeGiro * dis) % 360;
                    transform.localRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(vertical, Vector3.up);
                    oldTouchPositions[0] = newTouchPosition;
                }
                else
                {
                    //Debug.Log("Right");
                    vertical = (vertical - velcoidadeDeGiro * dis) % 360;
                    transform.localRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(vertical, Vector3.down);
                    oldTouchPositions[0] = newTouchPosition;
                }
            }
        }[/ICODE]
```

Comment: Try putting the code inside a FixedUpdate method instead of an Update method.

Comment: Is this 2D or 3D?